# How set the default value for my slider?

Tags: ipad, uislider

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UISlider how to set the initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878944/uislider-how-to-set-the-initial-value)

I want to set the default value for my slider and start the thumb of the slider from that value only.
Any suggestions???

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you want the change the lowest value, or merely set the thumb to a certain initial value?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Guys, problem is not getting the slider's current value but to set the thumb to that value initially by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the lowest potential value via the `minimumValue` method, the highest via the `maximumValue` method and the current value via the `value` method, all of which expect the value to be expressed as a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

See the [UISlider class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs for more information.

Comment: Guys, problem is not getting the slider's current value but to set the thumb to that value initially by default

Comment: @Ashutosh As I mentioned, you can use the `value` method to *set* the initial value - check the class reference docs I link above. (e.g.: `[theNameOfYourUISlider setValue:0.5];` etc.)